# Electro magnetic interference with Arduino Uno and a portable radio

Tags: arduino, rf, radio, emc, interference

I'm surprised when I'm working with Arduino Uno, by just sitting beside a portable radio, like when I was powered on both Arduino & Radio and when they are close to each other I got some noise issue in the audio of radio, later I tested with my mobile but didn't get that issue . I got to know later it's because of EM interference. Can anyone please share your views, why I got the issue with Arduino and why not with mobile?

Comment: The mobile is a complete system with built-in screening and interference mitigation. The Arduino is only a component - you supply the rest of the system yourself. Including that screening if the interference annoys you or stops other systems working.

Comment: @Brain drummond ,  what is the precautions that manufacturers taking while designing mobiles to mitigate interference issue (EMI) , Like What are the extra (specific) components that they are adding to the sysytem .

Comment: What is the frequency of your "radio"? 100MHz, which is above the clock rate of Arduino.

Comment: A mobile phone doesn't have to add anything extra to avoid interference from your Arduino.  The mobile phone signal is at a much higher frequency than the radio - at those frequencies, the interference from the Arduino will be **far** weaker.  The other thing is that the mobile phone doesn't just directly convert the analog RF signal to an audio signal like your radio does.  The voice on a mobile phone is transmitted in a very complex way.  Anything that doesn't match its way of working won't be heard - the phone itself won't even "hear" it.

Comment: AM radio is most susceptible to this kind of problem.  Can't say I've ever heard it on an FM radio.

Comment: @JRE , Here my concern is , there are some references like "Any electronic device which acts as EMI source when it powers up" , So in the same way when I took arduino near to radio got noise from audio of the radio , in other case when I took my mobile near to radio  didn't get any noise from the audio of radio , So wondered to know what are the difference or extra precautions taken incase of arduino and mobiile ?

Comment: Most radios are build using ancient designs from a time way before radio directives. They most often do not conform to ie the EU Radio Equipment Directive, and are therefore illegal but sold anyway. Whereas your mobile phone does conform to such directives and has been properly tested for immunity and emissions. The Ardunio is sold as a development board and thus except from all requirements, unless put inside a commercial product.

Comment: @Lundin:  There ain't no way to make an AM radio **not** react to garbage.  It's in the nature of the beast, and no norms or EU directives will change that.  New or old design, AM radios **will** pick up interference.  You canna legislate the laws of physics.

Comment: @JRE Of course you can build them less sensitive to EMI. Pass-band filters. Clean supply voltage and ground. PCB and antenna layout. Means of screening. Etc. I doubt most of these measures are in place in old AM radio, and that has nothing to do with laws of physics.